# Pushing values into multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP and retrieve user info, make a calculation, and then I'd like to add that calculation into the array per user

After looking up a user, this is the structure of the array

```
print_r($user_info);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [email] => admin@gmail.com
                    [website] => www.admin.com

                )

        )

)
```

Now I'm trying to add a 'num_payments' key for this particular user in a loop

```
array_push($user_info[$i]['User'],array('num_payments' => $customer_payments[$i]['num_payments']));
```

Here's the resulting array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [email] => admin@gmail.com
                    [website] => www.admin.com
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [num_payments] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How can I get it into this structure?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [email] => admin@gmail.com
                    [website] => www.admin.com
                    [num_payments] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without `array_push`:

```
$user_info[$i]['User']['num_payments'] = $customer_payments[$i]['num_payments'];
```

Comment: So just loop through the values?

Comment: Wow, that was painfully obvious. Time to step away from the keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$user_info[$i]['User']['num_payments'] = $customer_payments[$i]['num_payments'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should add a `join` to your query to pull in the data combined with the user data. Then you can use the `Hash::combine` method to merge the data into the array it belongs to.

However, if you are just running a loop on the data, you should be able to add it like:

```
foreach ($user_info as $i -> $data) {
  $user_info[$i]['User']['num_payments'] = $customer_payments[$i]['num_payments'];
}
```

This is assuming that `$i` corresponds to the same record in both arrays.

If `$i` in `$customer_payments` corresponds to the `User.id`, then it will require that you do this:

```
foreach ($user_info as $i -> $data) {
  $user_info[$i]['User']['num_payments'] = $customer_payments[$user_info[$i]['User']['id']]['num_payments'];
}
```